# Creating a Generic Class Member for Extra Info

Tags: c#, class, generics, member

I'm very new to C# (this is my first C# project). I'm fairly confident with the basics, but I'm starting to run into things that are raising issues that I can't quite solve, no matter how many different ways I Google it. A LOT of my questions have been answered by this site. :]
So, since I can't find the answer to this question, I decided to post it myself.

Maybe it's too basic of a question that everyone pretty much knows it, but I couldn't figure this out from the MSDN reading.

It has to do with C# Generics. I'm programming for a video game engine, and I've created a simple messaging system between AI units. The Message class contains members like sender, receiver, dispatchTime, and extraInfo. I want to use the extraInfo member to be a useful, flexible addition to the Message class, so I would like for it to be able to contain any type (an int node index, a double path cost, a relevant Vector3 position from XNA, etc, etc...). My research for this pointed me in the direction of Generics.

I figured out how to use Generics in something like a List, but I haven't read anything about how to just declare and implement a generic -member-. Just a single member, not a collection.

How would I declare this member, extraInfo? Additionally, when accessing it from another class, I would like to be able to type:

```
    info = message.extraInfo;
```

..to retrieve the extra information via the get property.

How would this be done in C#?

Comment: question doesn't make much sense (to me at least)

Comment: What can I explain further? I'd be happy to.

Comment: are you perhaps referring to a 'Property Bag'?

Comment: I have not heard of one.. I'll go research and read what that's all about.

Comment: This sounds like it might be close to what I'm talking about. But it seems like a great deal of complication just to make sure that -one- class member can keep its type undetermined until it's needed. This sounds like the entire class is structured to enable this sort of generic member idea. I really only need it for the extraInfo member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .NET 4.0, you can make your `ExtraInfo` property of type `dynamic`. You could then store anything at all in it, and as long as you access it properly at runtime, you'll be ok.

Comment: This is what I implemented. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Your message class would look something like this

```
public class Message<T>
{
     public object Sender { get; set; }
     public object Receiver { get; set; }
     public T ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
     Message<double> doubleMessage = new Message<double>() { ExtraInfo = 4.0d };
     Message<string> stringMessage = new Message<string>() { ExtraInfo = "Hello World" };
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking specifically in terms of generics syntax. I thought it would be something like this, but just couldn't nail it. Thank you for clarifying the syntax for me. I will remember this. This is useful because it allows for other variables to also be of this generic type.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the extraInfo member of your class as an `object`. You could then put anything you want in there.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, actually... But then when I tried to retrieve it, it said the conversion could not be made. For example, the navigation graph is divided by nodes. Some messages are associated with a node, so for its extraInfo, it makes sense to store the int node index. But when I tried to assign it to something else to retrieve it ("int index = message.extraInfo"), that's when I get the error.

Comment: That's the downside: You have to cast it back to the correct type in order to use it. Ex: `int index = (int)message.extraInfo;`

Comment: My answer, though, avoids that and contains some extra features.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by creating an ExtraInfoType object that contains an 
object as well as implicit operators to convert to and from the various object types transparently.
The ExtraInfoType object can also indicate what kind of object is stored in the ExtraInfoType.

An example of this implementation is below.

```
enum ExtraInfoKind
{
    Integer,
    Double
}

class ExtraInfoType
{
    object value;

    public object Value {
        get { return value; }
    }
    ExtraInfoKind kind;

    public ExtraInfoKind Kind {
        get { return kind; }
    }

    private ExtraInfoType(object o, ExtraInfoKind kind){
        this.value=o;
        this.kind=kind;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(ExtraInfoType o){
        if(o.kind!= ExtraInfoKind.Integer)
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        return (int)o.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator double(ExtraInfoType o){
        if(o.kind!= ExtraInfoKind.Double)
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        return (double)o.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator ExtraInfoType(int o){
        return new ExtraInfoType(o, ExtraInfoKind.Integer);
    }
    public static implicit operator ExtraInfoType(double o){
        return new ExtraInfoType(o, ExtraInfoKind.Double);
    }
}

 /* Example
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtraInfoType t=1;
        Console.WriteLine(t.Kind);
        int valueT=t;
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
 */
```

Here you would declare `extraInfo` under the type `ExtraInfoType`.
Note that no generics are necessary here.  Note also that ExtraInfoType
can store only one kind of object, which can be determined by the Kind property.
If the object is cast to the wrong type, an InvalidCastException is thrown, as
can be seen in the implicit operators above.

Comment: This is a little more complicated than I needed to get with this specific problem. With that being said, however, this is very clean and certainly looks effective. I appreciate the answer, and I'll remember it should I run into another situation like this!